# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected. SQL not returning values when executed through API

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have query that returns a result when executed in the database. But it does not return anything when I execute it from my application, it just keep on executing.

Below is the code snippet I have:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct c.ROWID_OBJECT, rc.CMPNY_NMBR from ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty rc " +
        "left join ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty_rel rel on rc.ROWID_OBJECT = rel.PTY_ID_1 " +
        "left join ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty c on rel.PTY_ID_2 =?1 " +
        "where rc.PTY_ROLE = 'L' and c.PTY_ROLE = 'L' and rel.REL_TP = 'is parent of' " +
        "and rc.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 and rel.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 and c.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 " +
        "AND ?2 IS NULL OR c.CMPNY_NMBR =?2 AND rel.PTY_ID_2 = c.ROWID_OBJECT", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getCompanyList(String ptyId, String cmpNumber);
```

The same query shows the result when run it through the database

```
  select distinct c.ROWID_OBJECT, rc.CMPNY_NMBR from ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty rc 
  left join ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty_rel rel on rc.ROWID_OBJECT = rel.PTY_ID_1 
  left join ecm_ors.dbo.c_b_pty c on rel.PTY_ID_2 = 493 
  where rc.PTY_ROLE = 'L' and c.PTY_ROLE = 'L' and rel.REL_TP = 'is parent of' 
  and rc.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 and rel.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 and c.HUB_STATE_IND = 1 
  and 02637 is null or c.CMPNY_NMBR =02637 
  and rel.PTY_ID_2 = c.ROWID_OBJECT
```

The problem I'm anticipating in this condition

```
  ?2 IS NULL OR c.CMPNY_NMBR =?2
```

Is it the kind of error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

I'm not seeing any errors though, REST call keep rotates.

Not sure how to rectify this, please advice.

Comment: When you say "But it does not return anything" do you mean when called from your application?

Comment: @DaleK yes Dale

Comment: Can you try something like this? `1 = ISNULL(?2, 1) OR c.CMPNY_NMBR =?2`

Comment: @Govind: No Govind, I tried that dint work, thank you though

Comment: You generally can't parameterize column names, only values.

Comment: I'm surprised the suggestion by @Govind doesn't work. You could try a less-than-ideal `c.CMPNY_NMBR = isnull(?2, c.CMPNY_NMBR)`. The main thing I wanted to point out, though, is that in the query as currently written, I think you *probably* want parentheses around that whole condition, don't you? `AND (?2 IS NULL OR c.CMPNY_NMBR =?2)`. Not that i think it would fix your specific issue, but it seems like what you probably intended`